# Can Node js projects be packaged as an EAR file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jakarta-ee, deployment, ear

I would like to deploy a node js project to Websphere. In order to do this it needs to be in an EAR file format. Is it possible to package Node js projects into EAR files? In development I am familiar with using node package manager, and the command npm start to run the server.js file. But I don't believe this is the correct approach for websphere.

Comment: In short, websphere hosts java web applications, a node.js application just won't run there.

Answer (score 0):

The packaging format is the least of your problems, these application servers use completely different programming languages (and different programming models/frameworks that your app has to comply to)